# Rails 3.1.10 - Homepage loads twice but if I add a trailing '/' to the URL it works fine (loads once)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

**Server**: Rails 3.1.10 and Ruby 1.9.2 on Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric).  **Client**: Windows 7, Chrome 29.0.1547.66 m.

I have a small but annoying problem: checking my logs, I see that my homepage loads twice.  Strangely though, it works correctly (loads only once) if I append a '/' to the URL.

This appeared after I removed some unneeded gems from bundler.  I also removed the require statement for 'rails/all' in my config file and instead am using selected railties because I don't need a DB/model.

I've checked the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786283/rails-seems-to-be-serving-the-page-twice) but no luck - there doesn't seem to be a missing asset source or href, and the double load also appears in 'incognito' browser mode.  I also tested after disabling all extensions on Chrome.

**application.rb**:

```
#require 'rails/all'  (commented out - active_record & test_unit are not needed)
#------------------------------------------ 
%w(
    action_controller
    action_mailer
    sprockets
).each do |framework|
    begin
        require "#{framework}/railtie"
    rescue LoadError
    end
end
```

**routes.rb**:

```
    match               '/'                 => 'pages#home'
    match               'root'              => 'pages#home'
    match               '/home'             => 'pages#home'
```

I've also tried:

```
    root                                    => 'pages#home'
    root    :to                             => 'pages#home'
```

*home* method in **pages_controller.rb**:

```
    def home
        render 'home'
    end
```

Thank you.

Comment: UPDATE:  Clearing all browsing data from Chrome did the trick.  I had tested before after clearing the browser cache only and that hadn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the problem that you are defining the `root` and `/`? Defining `/` shouldn't be needed.

Normally I just define: `root :to => 'pages#home'`

Comment: Unfortunately no.  I tried that line before on its own (commenting out all other references to home, ) and it still double loads.