# Rails Logger appears to be duplicating log lines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, ruby-on-rails-4

I am experiencing something curious with the rails logger.

When I insert a Rails.logger.info("Some text") in the code, usually to trace flow, I am getting two lines of "Some text" output in the console.

This ordinarily isn't much of a problem, but when I dump the contents of larger objects, the output can get cumbersome to wade through.

This never seemed to happen before I upgraded to Rails 4, or at least, I don't recall it happening.

Does anyone know what is happening here, and if there is a way to stop duplicating log output?

Comment: may be the line is executed twice, double check flow of execution. Or test it by putting same line at another location.

Comment: that's not how it is supposed to be. search for the places where you are configuring your logger and post them here.

Comment: It's not the flow of execution, if I have two or more logging statements in the same method, when each logging statement is called there are two lines generated. So I'll see, in order, 2x log line 1, 2x log line 2, 2x logline 3, and so on.

Comment: phoet, I haven't done any logger config. Just using the standard Rails.logger output to console.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try moving the rails_12factor gem (if you've got it installed) to the production group.

```
group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Comment: Amazing! not only did this solve the duplicate lines issue, but colorized log finally work...

# Gemfile
group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

Comment: gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production

Comment: God bless you! So annoying

Comment: How did you know this was the issue?

Answer (score 1):

This small workaround solved my issue. Follow these steps:

Under Rails External Libraries, Search for railties module. Go to this path: /lib/commands/server.rb

In this file comment this line, Rails.logger.extend(ActiveSupport::Logger.broadcast(console))

This command will switch off broadcasting, and just restart your rails server. You will not see any repeated logs anymore. Happy coding.

For more info checkout this issue page of rails:
https://github.com/heroku/rails_stdout_logging/issues/1