# Rails serving pages twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Running into a wierd error where rails 4 is serving pages twice.

Tried the solutions

- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786283/rails-seems-to-be-serving-the-page-twice) but no dice
- The assets are not precompiled so no conflict there.

I'm stumped. Any idea what might be going on?

Here are the server logs. Development and production modes suffer the same problem.

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:23 +0800
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:23 +0800
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.2ms)
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.2ms)
DEPRECATION WARNING: link_to_function is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 4.1. We recommend using Unobtrusive JavaScript instead. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#unobtrusive-javascript. (called from _app_views_layouts__drawer_html_erb__3283824921749738462_70245236444620 at /Users/macintosh/rails_projects/moneybaby/app/views/layouts/_drawer.html.erb:3)
DEPRECATION WARNING: link_to_function is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 4.1. We recommend using Unobtrusive JavaScript instead. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#unobtrusive-javascript. (called from _app_views_layouts__drawer_html_erb__3283824921749738462_70245236444620 at /Users/macintosh/rails_projects/moneybaby/app/views/layouts/_drawer.html.erb:3)
  Rendered layouts/_drawer.html.erb (75.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_drawer.html.erb (75.9ms)
DEPRECATION WARNING: link_to_function is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 4.1. We recommend using Unobtrusive JavaScript instead. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#unobtrusive-javascript. (called from _app_views_layouts__header_html_erb__2675263796791980695_70245236072180 at /Users/macintosh/rails_projects/moneybaby/app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:27)
DEPRECATION WARNING: link_to_function is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 4.1. We recommend using Unobtrusive JavaScript instead. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#unobtrusive-javascript. (called from _app_views_layouts__header_html_erb__2675263796791980695_70245236072180 at /Users/macintosh/rails_projects/moneybaby/app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:27)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 108ms (Views: 107.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 108ms (Views: 107.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)  

Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:23 +0800
Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:23 +0800 

Started GET "/assets/foundation_and_overrides.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800
Started GET "/assets/foundation_and_overrides.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800  

Started GET "/assets/header_and_footer.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800
Started GET "/assets/header_and_footer.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800

Started GET "/assets/layout.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800
Started GET "/assets/layout.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800

Started GET "/assets/life_insurances.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800
Started GET "/assets/life_insurances.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800

Started GET "/assets/static_pages.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800
Started GET "/assets/static_pages.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800

Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800
Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800

Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.abide.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.abide.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800

Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800
Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800

Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800

Started GET "/assets/vendor/modernizr.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800
Started GET "/assets/vendor/modernizr.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800

Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.accordion.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.accordion.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800

Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.clearing.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.clearing.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800

Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.dropdown.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.dropdown.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800

Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.interchange.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.interchange.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800

Started GET "/assets/logoblue.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800
Started GET "/assets/logoblue.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800

Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.alert.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.alert.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800

Started GET "/assets/logodark.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800
Started GET "/assets/logodark.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800

Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.tab.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.tab.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800

Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.orbit.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.orbit.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800

Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.offcanvas.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.offcanvas.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800

Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.magellan.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.magellan.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800

Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.joyride.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.joyride.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800

Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.reveal.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.reveal.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800


Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.tooltip.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.tooltip.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800

Started GET "/assets/foundation.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800
Started GET "/assets/foundation.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800

Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.topbar.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800
Started GET "/assets/foundation/foundation.topbar.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800

Started GET "/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800
Started GET "/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800

Started GET "/assets/life_insurances.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800
Started GET "/assets/life_insurances.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800

Started GET "/assets/static_pages.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800
Started GET "/assets/static_pages.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800

Started GET "/assets/zepto_slideupdown.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800
Started GET "/assets/zepto_slideupdown.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800

Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800
Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 16:29:24 +0800
```

Comment: Can you give us any info on your environment (browser, controller code, gems, etc)?

Comment: Hello again Rich! After banging my head against the wall for 16 hours turns out its just a bug with the STDOUT logger. The links is below. Thanks for taking an interest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was an issue with rails STDOUT logging.

Refer to the following links for more info:

[Exact problem I'm having](https://github.com/gkop/heroku-rails-4-duplicate-logs/issues/1)

[Issue tracked here](https://github.com/heroku/rails_stdout_logging/issues/1)

I only realized that the page wasn't being SERVED twice when using Chrome to analyse the timeline. Assets were only loaded once. Deduced that it was the logger. Googled "rails log twice" and now I'm off to the pub.