# HTTP request received twice at Rails Controller with same URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, http, http-headers, spree

I am using Rails 3.2.14 and Spree 2-0-stable but don't know if its actually related to Spree. User clicks on a link that takes to a merchandise customisation page. As I understand, http requests to fetch the product will get invoked along with other requests for the assets.

This is happening but I am receiving one more request that contains the same URL as the main request initiated at the start. This is causing problems as the route is leading to the same controller and the entire processing is repeated twice. I used live http headers to have a close look at the headers and found something unusual. Capturing those fields:

Main Request(Few fields from the HTTP header):

```
http://localhost:3000/products/birthday-candles?products%5Bproduct_id%5D=40&products%5Bvariant_id%5D=102&quantity=1    
GET /products/birthday-candles?products%5Bproduct_id%5D=40&products%5Bvariant_id%5D=102&quantity=1 HTTP/1.1    
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8    
Referer: http://localhost:3000/cards/showcase?taxon=Birthday+Products
```

---

Second Request(Few excerpts from the HTTP header):

```
http://localhost:3000/products/birthday-candles?products%5Bproduct_id%5D=40&products%5Bvariant_id%5D=102&quantity=1#    
GET /products/birthday-candles?products%5Bproduct_id%5D=40&products%5Bvariant_id%5D=102&quantity=1 HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5
Referer: http://localhost:3000/products/birthday-candles?products%5Bproduct_id%5D=40&products%5Bvariant_id%5D=102&quantity=1
```

---

Complete snapshot of the http header logs can be found at [setupHttpLogs](https://gist.github.com/suyashtripathi/8430065).

After Second request, I see some 5-6 more images from the assets being fetched.

However, Second request also contains the URL same as the referrer hence I am suspecting some circular dependency but have not been able to nail down one.

What does a circular reference signify as observed in the second request? What could be the possible ways to debug and resolve it?

Any help/pointers will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your network panel to see if your javascript/css is sending a bad URL and then your Check your third party addons and JS/CSS for a beacon.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5786750/94668

Comment: Apologies @TomFuertes, getting back on it quite late. Was caught up with other critical issues. Thanks for sharing the useful reference. Yes indeed that was the case. <img> src set as "#" was trying to fetch the asset using the same url and hence causing the circular initialisation behaviour. Have replaced "#" with correct image source and find the behaviour normal and as expected.